# Saving unknown number of rows/columns into a string list

Tags: c#, list, sqldatareader

I'm fairly new to C#, so please bear with me. I have a class `FixData`:

```
private class FixData
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public List<string> content { get; set; }
}
```

And there's also `private List<FixData> IDList = new List<FixData>();`

I'm querying data from sql database using IDs already stored in `IDList` and`SqlDataReader` and then trying to save it into `IDList.content`. But that's where the hard part starts. I don't really know how many rows or columns this data has and trying to read that from debugger made me so much more confused (in other words: I fail to read it). Despite this, I tried to save it in so many ways and so many times that I'm completly lost at this point. Here's the code:

```
foreach (var record in IDList)
{
    SqlCommand nonQuerycmd = new SqlCommand(NonQuery, connection);
    nonQuerycmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("ScenarioID", record.ID));
    nonQuerycmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(FixQuery, connection);
    sqlreader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    ArrayList rowList = new ArrayList();
    while (sqlreader.Read())
    {
        object[] values = new object[sqlreader.FieldCount];
        sqlreader.GetValues(values);
        rowList.Add(values);
        record.content = values.Cast<object>().Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList();
    }
    sqlreader.Close();
}
```

Could you please help me and point me to an explanation or link or something that could help me understand how I should solve this?

## Edit

I've managed to scramble something, but I'm not sure if this works as it was intended to.

Comment: There's quite a lot going on with that. Tell you what - if you can edit your question to add the SQL of the two different database queries you want to make, I'll try to fix that method for you.

Comment: Uh, but my sql queries are fine and working as intended, my problem is with handling the data I receive as a result of these queries.

Comment: I know that. You want to save what is in the reader to IDList.Content. I need to know what's in your select statement (or what's in your table) to help with that.

Comment: You say, "I don't really know how many rows or columns this data has". What format would the string you store in `content` have?

Comment: "in other words: I fail to read it". This makes it sound like you can't read the data from the db. Yet you wrote in comment that "sql queries are fine and working as intended". Can you please explain further what the actual problem is?

Comment: um, I think I um, answered your um, question. If not, put enough information in your question to allow someone to answer it. And welcome to SO.

Comment: The SQL queries were provided to me as sth to work on, you can pretty much assume I have no insight into the database.<br>
By 'fail to read' I meant the `SqlDataReader` in debugger, not the data from db.<br>
Here are the Select statements: http://pastebin.com/mhSNQAbw

Comment: @user6807975: can you explain how `SqlDataReader` is not reading in debug? For example, is the `while` loop being skipped, is an exception being thrown, or is something else unexpected happening?

Comment: >I< fail (don't know how, finding the data I'm interested in is like trying to find an exit of a maze) to read the debugger's `SqlDataReader`, not the other way around. ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing what's in your table, the best I can do is:

```
if (read.Read())
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < read.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                record.content.Add(Convert.ToString(read[i]));
            }

        }
```

This will add every field selected to record.content as a string. I just changed "while" to "if" because you will only be handling one row (I think). If you need more help, let us know more information about your data and what you need. If, for some reason, you are putting multiple fields from multiple rows, use while. If you only want one field from multiple rows, change if to while, take out the for/next and change [i] to [0]. Shannon is not Carnac the Magnificent.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [the MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader(v=vs.110).aspx) for `SqlDataReader` class. It should get you started.

The examples and other classes linked to there should help with proper usage of `SqlCommand` and other classes as well.

Comment: By the way, this link and the examples found through that link also show how to read data and assign - which is what you will want to fill in for the body of your while statement.